# Shortcut showing that a sequence is not null

Tags: sequences-and-series

I just wanted to ask if anybody here could be kind enough to verify that I understood the following "shortcut" correctly.

In an assignment I was doing, there was a auxiliary task that needed to be done, which was to show that $\{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+2}\}$ is not a null sequence. Now, my approach was as follows. I looked at the odd and even subsequences and showed that they had different limits, and from that, inferred that the sequence was divergent and thus not a null sequence.

Now, in the proposed solution. The author of the book I'm reading just goes

$$
 \left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+2}\right| = \frac{n}{n+2} \to 1
$$
and concludes that the sequence therefore is not a null sequence.

Now, this is clearly easier than my approach. But, I just want to be sure that my understanding of why his approach work, is correct.

I'm guessing what he is doing is, by taking the absolute value he is just looking a the subsequence when $n$ is odd, and since that tends to 1 as $n \to \infty$ he makes his conclusion that $\{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+2}\}$ either tends to 1, in case that the even subsequence also tends to 1. Or that $\{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+2}\}$ is divergent (in case the even subsequence tends to something else than 1). Since, neither scenarios leads to a null sequence, he concludes that $\{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+2}\}$ is not null.

Is this a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not necessary to consider the subsequence in your case.

Note that $\left| \left( -1\right) ^{n}\right| =1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N} $ and $\left| ab\right| =\left| a\right| \left|b\right| $ for $a,b\in R.$

The author' prove is correct.

*If $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, then $\left| x_{n}\right| \rightarrow \left| x\right| .$*

*The sequence $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$ iff $\left| x_{n}\right| \rightarrow 0 .$*

Take the contrapositive of the above.

If $\left| x_{n}\right|$ is not a null sequence, then $x_{n}$ is also not a null sequence .

Since$$\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+2}\right| = \frac{n}{n+2}$$ is not a null sequence, then

$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+2}$$ is also not a null sequence.

You can prove for any $\varepsilon > 0  $,  there exists $n\in \mathbb{N} $ such that for $k\geq n$ , we have $$\left| \dfrac {n} {n+2}-1\right|  < \varepsilon $$.